# How to select items from a Vaadin-listBox?

Tags: java, listbox, vaadin, listboxitem

I am trying to select an item from a Vaadin listBox element.
I fill the listBox with an array list of objects from a database. After selecting an object/ list-Item,
i want to fill text fields with the attributes of the selected object.
This is my code so far. I´ve tried so much but can´t get it to work propperly :/

```
// creating a ArrayList - listOfItems - filled with Items from the Database

        listBox.setItems(listOfItems);
        listBox.setHeight("100px");
        add(listBox);

        Div value = new Div();
        listBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
            if (event.getValue() == null) {
                Notification.show(event.getValue().toString());
            } else {
                Notification.show("value is null");
            }
        });
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug here:

```
        listBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
            if (event.getValue() == null) {
                Notification.show(event.getValue().toString());
            } else {
                Notification.show("value is null");
            }
        });
```

In the first part of the `if` statement, you call `event.getValue().toString()`, which will cause a null pointer exception, as `event.getValue()` is null. So flip the condition to `if (event.getValue() != null)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.setValue(...)` method of the ListBox class. But as you are loading your data from the database you have to ensure that the item you are selecting is exactly the same as one of the items you have provided via `.setItems(...)` method. That means, that one of the provided items has to have the exactly same hashCode as the item you want to select. Otherwise your selection may not work.

For some examples just look at: https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-list-box/java-examples